# linked list returning none when specified not too

Tags: python, list, return

I'm creating a singly linked list that returns odd numbers in a given range, instead of returning 1, 3, 5, etc it is returning 1, None, 3, None, 5, etc. I want to make it so that it stops returning None and only odd numbers.

```
class Odds:
    def __init__(self,end):
        self.__start = 1
        self.__end = end

    def __iter__(self):
        return OddsIterator(self.__end)

class OddsIterator:
    def __init__(self,finish): 
        self.__current = 0
        self.__step = 1
        self.__end = finish

    def __next__(self):
        x = None
        if self.__current > self.__end:
            raise StopIteration 
        else:
            self.__current += self.__step 
            if (self.__current - self.__step + 1) % 2 != 0:
                x = self.__current - self.__step + 1
        if x != None:
            return x
```

Comment: Stop using double-decker name-mangling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `None` is being returned is that it's possible to reach the end of `__next__` without a `return` statement, in which case any Python function returns `None`. The solution here is to set `self.__step = 2` and `self.__current = 1` when you initialize. You can also remove the `if x != None:`, since it does nothing. There are some other small changes I've made below to fit with this new definition of `self.__current`. Currently the code below will not include the final value, if you want it to then change `self.__current >= self.__end` to `self.__current > self.__end`.

```
class Odds:
    def __init__(self,end):
        self.__start = 1
        self.__end = end

    def __iter__(self):
        return OddsIterator(self.__end)

class OddsIterator:
    def __init__(self,finish):
        self.__current = 1
        self.__step = 2
        self.__end = finish

    def __next__(self):
        x = None
        if self.__current >= self.__end:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            return_value = self.__current
            self.__current += self.__step
            return return_value

odds = Odds(21)
print(list(odds))
```

Comment: Changing the step to 2 changes means that if an odd number is used for the end, then it will return one more than it should i.e. `Odds(22)` will have 23 at the end

Comment: Good catch! I've fixed that now, and hopefully made the logic a bit clearer.

Comment: Thank you, I added in an `if` statement in the `__init__` function to minus 1 from the end value if an odd number is input, cheers!